# VSTO Ribbon ComboBox with separator (MenuSeparator)

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I'm doing an addon for Excel and I would like to create a combobox with a functionality similar to the fonts combobox. The fonts allows has both icons and separators:

[image: Excel fonts menu]

I managed to set images on the drop down (standard functionality) but I cannot find any reference on how to create the separators.

DynamicMenu have the ability to add separators but the user is not allowed to type and have the autosuggest functionality like in the combobox control. I need this functionality because the list is going to be long.

Does anyone knows how to do this functionality or point me to a blog which suggest how to do this? 
If this is not possible, does anyone knows how to create custom controls which will permit me to do these functionality by myself? Specially the drawing of the combobox list.

Comment: Which type of ribbon are you using - XML or classic (Visual designer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, Microsoft hasn't exposed all the things it can make the Ribbon do to developers. The kind of separators you see in the Font listing are not exposed for dropdowns in the Office Ribbon XML schema available to developers.

The `menuSeparator` is not available for dropdown controls. This is quite clear in the information available in [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Under `dropDown` the only entry for "Children" is `item`. Available "Children" for `menu` includes `menuSeparator`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what I deducted from my researches. But is there a way at least to create custom controls in the ribbon?

Comment: No, unfortunately there's not. If you need more flexibility in the interface, then a Custom Task Pane could handle that. You can create a custom UserControl (as in a WinForms user control) and use that in a CTP.